# Django queryset and select_related()

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a small probleme concerning django querysets and select_related.

With this model :

```
class DeviceGroup(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
  owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Device(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  address = models.GenericIPAddressField()
  port = models.IntegerField()
  group =    models.ForeignKey(DeviceGroup)

class Sensor(models.Model):
  device = models.ForeignKey(Device)
```

I'd like to get a list like :

```
- group 1
  - device 1
  - device 2
  - device 3
    -sensor 1
- group 2
- group 3
  - device 4
  - device 5
    - sensor 2
```

I've read the doc about select_related(), but I don't know how to do because I've to start my query bu group cause, it's directly linked to logged user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to present it this way in a Django template, you probably want to use `regroup`:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

The new docs is slightly more obfuscate, I find the old docs version easy to comprehend (this eg from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup ):

```
{% regroup people by gender as gender_list %}

<ul>
{% for gender in gender_list %}
    <li>{{ gender.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in gender.list %}
        <li>{{ item.first_name }} {{ item.last_name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Where in your case:

from view.py

```
group = Group.objects.all()
```

template.html

```
{% regroup groups by device as device_list %}
```

Comment: I think, gorjuce wants to select `Sensor` objects related to some user by one query, not all object.

Comment: thnks for the answer, but it would be a model problem i guess. I'm a PHP dev, and it's boring cause, i know it's simple joins !!

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to optimize or change my model.
If i can't query it, it's maybe a model problem and not a queryset problem  :)